# Ext js 4.2 destroy component

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs, removechild

How can I correctly destroy a component inside `Ext js 4.2` According to the docs:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component there is no destroy method. My components are children of a container so I have tried `container.remove('componentReference')` but this is giving me unexpected behaviour, so is there any way to remove the component itself.

Comment: There is but it's private (click the "show" button in the top right corner). You can still use it though.

Comment: That is surely not a recommended way I guess

Comment: I guess so. A private method is intended to be accessed internally, refering to it from other methods of the same class. So, you could break the rule by calling it from the instance, or you could use the recommended way which is to create a subclass of the Component class.

Comment: Javascript allows to break the rules, the hard part is not to give in to temptation :) For that matter, I think this is the reason for being of ExtJS since it provides a frame to keep you on the right track, as much as possible. I mean, this is not just a library or a set of UI components. Maybe you have already read the documentation about how they implement the [MVC pattern](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture).

Comment: That said, it's up to you to decide whether you want to break the rules. In some cases, doing such a choice appears to be more logical and can save many time (can you hear the devil whispering?).

Comment: Well using the destroy method on an concrete instance of the component gives me unexpected behaviour. Two components get destroy. Any ideas why maybe?

Comment: Nope they are siblings added using container.add() always on the same container...

Comment: Method called in a loop?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47232/discussion-between-wared-and-jacob)

Comment: Nope! It is called on gridPanelItemClick which removes an item from the store(grid) and if then no items are left, the container(component) containing the grid gets removed

Comment: It's not private, it's just a documentation generation error. `destroy` is part of the public API.

Answer (score 3):

A component usually is destroyed when it is removed from its owning container, unless you configure your container not to do so.

Refer to the [autoDestroy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-cfg-autoDestroy) config and the [remove](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-remove) function of `Ext.container.AbstractContainer`.

Furthermore, for `Ext.panel.Panel` and classes extending it there is a [close](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-close) function, which will also result in destruction of the component, unless a different [closeAction](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-closeAction) is specified.

That being said, there might be scenarios where it can actually be useful to directly invoke a component's [destroy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-destroy) function although this is marked as private, e.g. when it has never been rendered (for whatever reason).